# Optimal transport and total variation distance

Tags: probability-theory, duality-theorems, optimal-transport, total-variation

I have a question regarding the following concept equating total variation distance with a particular case of optimal transport.

[image]

I don't understand why equality (6.11) holds.  We know by Kantorovich duality that the RHS is equal to $$2 \sup_{\phi \text{ Lipschitz} \\ |\phi|_{\text{Lip}} \leq 1} \int \phi d\mu - \int \phi d\nu \equiv f(\mu, \nu)$$ as a function is $c-$convex for a distance function $c = 1(x \ne y)$ if and only if it is $1-$Lipschitz.

As for the **total variation**, it is defined as
$$T(\mu, \nu) \equiv  \sup_{A \in \mathcal{F}} |\mu(A) - \nu(A)|$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is our $\sigma-$algebra on whichever Polish space we're working with.  It is obvious that for $\phi(x) = 1_A(x)$, we have that $\phi$ is $1-$Lipschitz and therefore $T(\mu, \nu) \leq f(\mu, \nu)$.  I'm confused **why we need the $2$ here, and how the other direction of the inequality would be shown?**

Specifically, I need that for any $1-$Lipschitz function, there exists a set $A \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $|\mu(A) - \nu(A)| \ge 2 \int \phi d\mu - \int \phi d \nu$, but I have no idea how to get this right.  Any help would be massively appreciated.

(The excerpt is from Villani (2009))

Comment: Could you please clarify the bit "function is c−convex for a distance function c=1(x≠y) if and only if it is 1−Lipschitz"? This is my difficulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is some difference in definition. Look the lecture notes Probability in High Dimensions by Van-Handel. In example 4.14 the author writes:

$$
||\mu - \nu||_{TV} = \inf_{M\in\mathcal C(\mu,\nu)}M(X\neq Y)
$$

And he then goes on to prove this.

What might be happening is a different definition of the T.V metric.

Indeed, we can prove that using your definition of TV, the equality
$$||\mu - \nu||_{TV} = \sup_A|\mu(A) - \nu(A)| = 2\inf P[X\neq Y]$$

Would be inconsistent. Note:

$$\mu(A) - \nu(A) = P[X \in A] - P[Y \in A] = $$
$$=
P[X \in A, X=Y] - P[X \in A,X\neq Y]+
P[Y \in A,X=Y] - P[Y \in A,X\neq Y] =
$$
$$
= P[X \in A, X\neq Y] - P[Y \in A, X \neq Y] \leq P[X\neq Y]
$$
Therefore,
$$\sup_A|\mu(A) - \nu(A)| \leq P[X\neq Y]$$
Hence, $\sup_A|\mu(A) - \nu(A)|>0 \implies 2P[X\neq Y]> \sup_A|\mu(A)-\nu(A)|$

Comment: Yes you're correct.  I am making a mistake in my definition of total variation.  Villani assumes the definition to be twice what I wrote down (but does not explicitly state this anywhere, as his way is probably standard/common).  Thanks for this answer.

Comment: No problems. If this helped you, please consider upvoting. Cheers